# error: (-215:Assertion failed) bmi && width >= 0 && height >= 0 && (bpp == 8 || bpp == 24 || bpp == 32) in function 'FillBitmapInfo

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I'm doing a violence detection project and I have trained my model using resnet but when I'm just printing probability it gives some error.

```
# import packages done

#load model
model = load_model('E:\Docs & Other\C-VS\ViolenceDetection\Resources\VDresnet152v2.h5') 
img_width, img_hight = 224, 224
#start  web cam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
 
#sart reading images and prediction
while True:
     
    #read image from webcam
    responce, color_img = cap.read()
   
     
    #if respoce False the break the loop
    if responce == False:
        break    
    #resize image with 50 % ratio
    color_img = cv2.resize(color_img,(224,224))     
    color_img = color_img.reshape(1,224,224,3) 
    
   
    pred_prob = model.predict(color_img)
    print(pred_prob[0][0].round(2))
    pred=np.argmax(pred_prob)
     
    # display image
    cv2.imshow('LIVE', color_img)
     
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
 
# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What am I doing wrong? when I run this code it gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after this line:

```
color_img = color_img.reshape(1,224,224,3)
```

color_img is a 4d tensor (with seperate color planes !), not usable with `cv2.imshow()`

please do not "recycle" variable names, esp. if their context changes.

```
color_img = cv2.resize(color_img,(224,224))     
color_tensor = color_img.reshape(1,224,224,3) 
pred_prob = model.predict(color_tensor)
...
cv2.imshow('LIVE', color_img)
```